# How recursion reduces the time complexity in merge sort

Tags: time-complexity, mergesort

As per my understanding, time complexity is derived by calculating increment in number of operations with increasing input size.

In merge sort, there are 2 phases.

1. Divide the input array into smaller array
2. Sort and Merge those arrays

As per a video lecture, time complexity to divide an array for a merge sort is `O(log n)`.

[image]

But here he is not referring the number of operations to calculate time complexity but number of decompressions or number of times recursive function is called.

*He used recursion to divide an array.

Talking purely in terms of pseudo code, recursion is taking more than `n` operations in this case;

[image]

Instead, this code always takes `n` operations;

```
function divide(arr){
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = [arr[i]];
   }
}
```

So how the complexity of recursive code is lesser than loop?

Answer (score 0):

Recursion doesn't reduce time complexity. You've already shown a diagram for top down merge sort. For the original bottom up merge sort, the code treats an array of n elements as n runs of size 1, for O(1) time complexity to divide the array.

Most libraries use some variation of a hybrid insertion sort and bottom up merge sort. Top down merge sort is mostly used for academic purposes.